# Putting li's into rows

Tags: css, html

I have a long list of li's.

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <img src="test.jpg">
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="test.jpg">
  </li>
  //etc
```

Each li has this styling:

```
width: 10%;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

When I get to more than 10 li's in a row, they go on to the next row.

Is this the correct way to do it? or should I wrap each 10 li's into something that breaks the line? What the best/correct method? i intialy chose this method as it would be easily to loop out data from a database.

Comment: What do you mean by "next row."..?

Comment: Provide minimalistic sample on jsFiddle which reproduces your issue.

Comment: as like this http://jsfiddle.net/ZmCZd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a perfectly valid method, and a very easy one to change. Let's say you decide actually, you want five on a line. Just change `10%` to `20%` and ta-da! Instantly done.

Just be aware that whitespace can be an issue, if you have spaces between your `<li>` elements (but if you're properly minifying your HTML, then you shouldn't have this issue).

Another point, it may be more meaningful to use a higher-level language such as LESS to generate your CSS. In LESS, you can do this:

```
width: (100% / 10);
```

This will calculate the percentage for you, with `10` being the number you want per line. What was already easy is now even easier (especially if you want, say, seven on a line). CSS `calc(100% / 10)` can do it too but it's not compatible with older browsers.

Comment: Thanks, could you explain more about the whitespace issue?

Comment: Basically, spaces... take space. When you do `display:inline-block`, the entire element is effectively treated as a single character in the current line of "text". If you set the width to something that should add up exactly to 100%, you may find elements falling short because of spaces. Easy fix is to just have `</li><li>` on the same line, with no space. In my projects, I strip out all non-essential `\r`, `\n` and `\t` characters, which does the job nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Just should create a div list with table properties. Like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9gDhP/)

```
.table{
    display:table;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.cell{
    margin:0;
    display:table-cell;
}
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```